# Upload to google drive using The files get uploaded, but, only in the root and are always named "Untitled"

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload files to Google drive using a REST API

Everything is working fine, but files are uploading into Google Drive only in the root, and with `"Untitled"` as their name.

```cs
public class UploadTODrive {

    public static DriveFiles UploadFileTODrive(String accessToken, MultipartFile files) throws IOException {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String requestUri = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files";
        System.out.println("ContentType==============: " + files.getContentType());
        byte[] s=files.getBytes();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", files.getContentType());
        headers.setContentLength(0); 
        //headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
        headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            HttpEntity<byte[]> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(s, headers);
            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(requestUri, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity,
                    String.class);
            System.out.println("=====>Response: " + response);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            DriveFiles driveFiles = gson.fromJson(response.getBody(), DriveFiles.class);
            
            
        return driveFiles;
    }

}
```

Comment: Posting some non-Delphi code and saying you are having problems in Delphi leaves your question unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Files are uploaded to google drive in two parts.

The first part is the meta data of the file, this being the name and the mimetype most often and occasionally containing a parent directory.

The second part is the upload of the actual file stream.

It seams that you are uploading the file stream but you have forgotten to post the file metadata.  This is posted in the body of your request

This is your HTTP Post request. You need to figure out how to add a post body to this. This is the documentation link to the writable fields that you can post [insert#request-body](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert#request-body)

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(requestUri, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity,
            String.class);
```

Update

found this with a bit of googling

```
RESTRequest1.AddBody('{"title": "Capture.jpg"}', TRESTContentType.ctAPPLICATION_JSON);
```